# How to set multiple color for a single border

Tags: html, css

I need to set multiple color for a single border like the below one. But here i used three td element in a tr. I need a single td element and border must be its (td's) bottom or top border.

```html
<table style="border-spacing:0px;margin-top:5%;margin-left:2%" cellpadding="0" width="25%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="5%" style="border-bottom: 3px solid red;">       </td>
      <td width="90%" style="border-bottom: 3px solid green;">
      </td>
      <td width="5%" style="border-bottom: 3px solid red;">       </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: You have not specified in what sense a border (and which border) should have multiple color. E.g., should it be red on weekdays, green on Sundays? Should it be a mix of them? How? A gradient? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

you can do by following way. Please check.

```css
.test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.test:before, .test:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 10px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, red 20px, blue 20px, blue 40px, yellow 40px, yellow 60px, green 60px, green 80px);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(0deg, red 20px, blue 20px, blue 40px, yellow 40px, yellow 60px, green 60px, green 80px);
  background-size: 80px;
}

.test:before {
  top: 0px;
}
.test:after {
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="test">
    1
  </td>
  <td class="test">
    2
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

With CSS `border` property we can create borders having single color only. However we can mimic this effect by using CSS3.

With `linear-gradient()` we can create a spectrum having as many colors as we want.

Below are few examples:

**Border having 2 colors:**

**Necessary CSS:**

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, green 50%);
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Borders with two colors]

**Working Example:**

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 10%, green 10%, green 90%, red 90%) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 3px;
  background-position: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<table style="border-spacing:0px;margin-top:5%;margin-left:2%" cellpadding="0" width="25%">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text here</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Border having 3 colors:**

**Necessary CSS:**

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 33.33%, green 33.33%,
                                            green 66.67%, red 66.67%);
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Border with three colors]

**Working Example:**

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 33.33%, green 33.33%, green 66.67%, red 66.67%) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 3px;
  background-position: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<table style="border-spacing:0px;margin-top:5%;margin-left:2%" cellpadding="0" width="25%">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text here</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo class for that:

```css
.box {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}

.box:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #bcbcbc 25%, #ffcd02 25%, #ffcd02 50%, #e84f47 50%, #e84f47 75%, #65c1ac 75%);
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 4px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td class="box"></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table style="border-spacing:0px;margin-top:5%;margin-left:2%" cellpadding="0" width="25%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="5%" style="border-left: 3px solid red;border-right: 3px solid red; border-top: 3px solid green;border-bottom: 3px solid green;">text     </td>
  
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, setting a regular border and using `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements to create the red parts.

```css
table {
  width: 25%;
}

td {
  border-bottom: 3px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

td:before,
td:after {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
}

td:before {
  left: 0;
}

td:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```